# How to split byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

its a simple code to split a byte array and see how it works. But the problem is I get weird outputs.

```
    public static void SplitArayUsingLinq()

    {
        int i = 3;
        string data = "123456789";
        byte[] largeBytes = Encoding .Unicode .GetBytes (data);
        byte[] first = largeBytes.Take(i).ToArray();
        byte[] second = largeBytes.Skip(i).ToArray();
        string firststring = Encoding.Unicode .GetString (first);
        string secondstring = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(second);
        Console.WriteLine(" first : " +firststring);
        Console.WriteLine(" second : " +secondstring);

    }
```

when the value of i=3 I get this:

[image]

and when the value of i=4 I get this:

[image]

In both cases I get weird outputs. It seems that whatever the value of i is given, the program seems to consider its half. Can anyone tell me why is it happening? exactly where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode uses two bytes per character, so only even values of `i` will work and it will take half the number of letters. If you just want to split a string doing [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be a lot easier.

```
int i = 3;
string data = "123456789";
string firststring = data.SubString(0,i);
string secondstring = data.SubString(i+1);

Console.WriteLine(" first : " +firststring);
Console.WriteLine(" second : " +secondstring);
```

Comment: no I don't want to split string. I just want to see how byte array is split and want to see how the "take()" and "skip()" works. thats why my code is the way it is. thanks anyway.

Comment: I would recommend printing out `largeBytes` in hex so you can understand what is going on.

Comment: @Giliweed Just to make sure you know, this isn't magic. UTF8 uses one byte per character.

Comment: Well, UTF8 uses one byte per character if the charater is in the standard ASCII set. As soon as you start doing stuff like `今日は` it will break again.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain,  so, what is the solution now for the Chinese characters? what should I use to make it possible for any character?

Comment: If you are splitting strings as bytes, you need to figure out where one character starts one one stops. That is a lot of work, that is why you should not attempt to split string arrays as bytes because you run in to problems like this. The way I would make it possible for any character... use String.SubString instead of working with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the Unicode to UTF8 and the problem is solved. Thanks everyone who answered and commented.

**UPDATE:**

the correct code is :

```
    public static void SplitArayUsingLinq()

    {
        int i = 3;
        string data = "123456789";
        byte[] largeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (data);
        byte[] first = largeBytes.Take(i).ToArray();
        byte[] second = largeBytes.Skip(i).ToArray();
        string firststring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (first);
        string secondstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(second);
        Console.WriteLine(" first : " +firststring);
        Console.WriteLine(" second : " +secondstring);

    }
```